# Webpack module federation lazy loading remoteEntry.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Am I able to lazy load apps' entry files when I am using React with ReactRouter? When I enter page there are many requests for `remoteEntry.js` files for each app I have. I do not want to fetch it at the beginning because of performance. I want to load them when I visit the route to particular app.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to use promise-based dynamic remotes.

For example, rather than define your remote as a URL:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'host',
      remotes: {
        app1: 'app1@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js',
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

You could delete this reference in `webpack.config.js` and define the remote as a promise which will be resolved at runtime:

```
const loadScope = (url: string, scope: string) => {
  const element: any = document.createElement('script');
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    element.src = url;
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    element.async = true;
    element.onload = () => resolve(window[scope]);
    element.onerror = reject;
  });
  document.head.appendChild(element);
  promise.finally(() => document.head.removeChild(element));
  return promise;
};

const loadModule = async (url: string, scope: string, module: string) => {
  try {
    const container = await loadScope(url, scope);
    await __webpack_init_sharing__('default');
    await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default);
    const factory = await container.get(module);
    return factory();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading module:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const MyApp = React.lazy(() =>
  loadModule(
    'http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js',
    'app1',
    './MyApp',
  ),
);
```

For further details, you can refer to the [Webpack 5 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#dynamic-remote-containers).

Answer (score -1):

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'reactParent',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    remotes: {
        reactChild: 'reactChild@/reactChild/remoteEntry.js',
        svelteChild: 'svelteChild@/svelteChild/remoteEntry.js',
        vueChild: 'vueChild@/vueChild/remoteEntry.js'
    }
})
```

Putting the paths to the remoteEntry.js files into your Webpack config gets the job done. In this example, my app is setup to proxy requests to the micro-frontends, so /reactChild is proxied to where the particular app is running.

Comment: How is this lazy loading?